# problems with for loop inside another for loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have problems in going through these two for loops, I need to get the same elements from the first array within the cycle, but the values ​​are being repeated. I know that they are repeated depending on the data of the second array.

I tried to make comparisons but I could not get the result I want.

```js
var array = [
{
  grouper: 1
},
{
  grouper: 2
},
{
  grouper: 3
},
{
  grouper: 4
},
];


var array2 = [
{
  value: 1,
  grouper: 1,
  status: 100
},
{
  value: 2,
  grouper: 2,
  status: 100
},
{
  value: 3,
  grouper: 3,
  status: 100
}
];


for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j<array2.length; j++){
      if(array2[j].grouper == array[i].grouper){
        console.log(array[i].grouper+'-'+array2[j].value);
      }
   }
}
```

This is the result I want, I need all the groupers from the first array and the values from the second array:

```
1-1
2-2
3-3
4-
```

The grouper 4, does not have value, but I need to show it.

I need the second array because I'm going to compare with the data from the second array

I do not know if I am doing the process wrong. I hope you can help me.

Comment: If you just want 1, 2, 3, then remove the second for loop. You don't need it.

Comment: What is the point of second loop `for(var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++)`?  It's not used in `console.log(array[i].grouper)`.

Comment: I am sorry, I need the secod for beacuse I need to make validations after @MikeCluck

Comment: I see your edit but I don't understand just yet. Do you mean to say that you want to check every value in `array2` and see if `value` matches one of the `grouper` values?

Comment: @Fabian Sierra What is the relationship between array and array2?

Comment: @FabianSierra What do you mean by validate?  Do you need to filter the first array depending on what's in the second array?

Comment: @DominiqueFortin I updated my question to understand my question better

Comment: @FabianSierra Based on my understanding of the problem, you just solved the issue. Could you please explain what you mean by "validate"?

Comment: @MikeCluck I mean "compare" the grouper value from the first array with to the second array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply track if there was a match (variable `shown`), and if there were not any, display a "half" line:

```js
var array = [{grouper: 1},{grouper: 2},{grouper: 3},{grouper: 4},];

var array2 = [
{value: 1, grouper: 1, status: 100},
{value: 2, grouper: 2, status: 100},
{value: 3, grouper: 3, status: 100}
];

for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
   var shown=false;
   for(var j = 0; j<array2.length; j++){
      if(array2[j].grouper == array[i].grouper){
        console.log(array[i].grouper+'-'+array2[j].value);
        shown=true;
      }
   }
   if(!shown){
     console.log(array[i].grouper+"-");
   }
}
```

Comment: Ohh that's awsome. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with the example you provided I believe you want to get back:

```
1,2,3
```

There is no 4th object inside of array2, so your conditional `(array2[j].grouper == array[i].grouper` will never evaluate to true.

The question here is whether you are always comparing the same indexes? In this example, you're comparing array[0] to array2[0] to see if grouper in array equals grouper in array2... that's it????

In that case you just do one loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i].grouper == array2[i].grouper) {
        console.log(array[i].grouper+'-'+array2[j].value);
      }
}
```

Comment: ... but what happens if the `grouper` items of both arrays are not in this matching parallel order?

Answer (score 0):

@FabianSierra ... with your provided example one just needs to handle the not fulfilled `if` clause/condition in the most inner loop.

A more generic approach additionally might take into account changing field names (keys). Thus a function and [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) / [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) based approach provides better code reuse. An example implementation then might look similar to that ...

```js
var array = [{ // in order.
  grouper: 1
}, {
  grouper: 2
}, {
  grouper: 3
}, {
  grouper: 4
}];

var array2 = [{ // not in the order similar to `array`.
  value: 22,
  grouper: 2,
  status: 200
}, {
  value: 33,
  grouper: 3,
  status: 300
}, {
  value: 11,
  grouper: 1,
  status: 100
}];


function collectRelatedItemValuesByKeys(collector, item) {
  var sourceKey = collector.sourceKey;
  var targetKey = collector.targetKey;
  var targetList = collector.targetList;
  var resultList = collector.result;

  var sourceValue = item[sourceKey];
  var targetValue;
  var relatedItem = targetList.find(function (targetItem) {

    return (targetItem[sourceKey] === sourceValue);
  });
  if (typeof relatedItem !== 'undefined') {

    targetValue = relatedItem[targetKey];

  } else if (typeof targetValue === 'undefined') {

    targetValue = ''; // `relatedItem` does not exist.
  }
  resultList.push([sourceValue, targetValue].join('-'));
  
  return collector;
}


var resultList = array.reduce(collectRelatedItemValuesByKeys, {

  sourceKey: 'grouper',
  targetKey: 'value',
  targetList: array2,
  result: []

}).result;

console.log('resultList : ', resultList);

resultList = array.reduce(collectRelatedItemValuesByKeys, {

  sourceKey: 'grouper',
  targetKey: 'status',
  targetList: array2,
  result: []

}).result;

console.log('resultList : ', resultList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```